# Automatic update on Progress Bar in MS Lists

Tags: power-automate, validation, mslists

I'm setting up a project tracker. Each project has 10 different stages. Within each stage I have 5 different choices - Waiting, Ongoing, Passed, Failed, Under Review.

I have a progress column that has like a donut circle loading percentage. Currently you can put the number in and it changes to what you put in. I want the progress to change automatically when "Passed" is selected in each stage.

So when I select "Passed" on Stage 1 then progress will be 10%, Stage 2 will move the dial to 20% and so on.

This is the code I have for the Progress column:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "position": "relative",
    "margin": "5px",
    "width": "48px",
    "height": "48px"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "svg",
      "style": {
        "fill": "currentColor",
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": "0",
        "right": "0"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "viewBox": "0 0 600 600",
        "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralQuaternaryAlt"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "path",
          "attributes": {
            "d": "M300,0 A300,300 0 1,1 299.998407846124,4.2249439502484165e-9 L299.99880588459297,75.00000000316868 A225,225 0 1,0 300,75 Z"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "elmType": "svg",
      "style": {
        "fill": "currentColor",
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": "0",
        "right": "0",
        "display": "=if(@currentField < 0 , 'none' , '')"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "viewBox": "0 0 600 600",
        "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "path",
          "attributes": {
            "d": "= 'M300,0 A300,300 0 ' + if(@currentField > 0.5 , '1,1 ' , '0,1 ') + (300 + 300 * sin(360 * if(@currentField > 1 , 1 , @currentField) * (3.14159 / 180))) + ',' + (300 - 300 * cos(360 * if(@currentField > 1 , 1 , @currentField) * (3.14159 / 180))) + ' L' + (300 + 225 * sin(360 * if(@currentField > 1 , 1 , @currentField) * (3.14159 / 180))) + ',' + (300 - 225 * cos(360 * if(@currentField > 1 , 1 , @currentField) * (3.14159 / 180))) + ' A225,225 0 ' + if(@currentField > 0.5 , '1,0 ' , '0,0 ') + ' 300,75 Z'"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "position": "absolute",
        "width": "100%",
        "height": "100%",
        "display": "flex",
        "flex-direction": "column",
        "justify-content": "center",
        "align-items": "center",
        "cursor": "pointer"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary"
      },
      "customCardProps": {
        "directionalHint": "rightCenter",
        "isBeakVisible": true,
        "openOnEvent": "hover",
        "formatter": {
          "elmType": "div",
          "style": {
            "padding": "15px"
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "font-size": "25px",
                "font-weight": "bold"
              },
              "txtContent": "@currentField.displayValue",
              "attributes": {
                "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "style": {
            "font-size": "30px"
          },
          "attributes": {
            "iconName": "SkypeCircleCheck"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried doing List Validation and Using Power Automate but I'm not getting anywhere.

[image]